# force legend in geom_tile (ggplot, R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-tile

I don't manage to add a continuous legend to a ggplot using geom_tile.

I had to manipulate the layer_data (for various reasons), hence obtaining a dataframe of the type:

```
data =
      fill x  y PANEL group xmin xmax ymin ymax colour size linetype alpha width height
1  #C4FFB1 1 19     1    19  0.5  1.5 18.5 19.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
2  #E7FFDE 1 20     1    20  0.5  1.5 19.5 20.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
3  #FAFFF8 1  1     1     1  0.5  1.5  0.5  1.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
4  #C7FFB5 1 13     1    13  0.5  1.5 12.5 13.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
5  #DFFFD3 1 10     1    10  0.5  1.5  9.5 10.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
6  #A3FF8B 1 15     1    15  0.5  1.5 14.5 15.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
7  #FAFFF8 1 18     1    18  0.5  1.5 17.5 18.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
8  #CEFFBC 1 17     1    17  0.5  1.5 16.5 17.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
9  #F5FFF0 1  5     1     5  0.5  1.5  4.5  5.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
10 #D9FFCB 1 25     1    25  0.5  1.5 24.5 25.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
11 #D3FFC4 1  4     1     4  0.5  1.5  3.5  4.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
12 #76FF5D 1 24     1    24  0.5  1.5 23.5 24.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
13 #5AFF44 1 23     1    23  0.5  1.5 22.5 23.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
14 #E4FFDA 1  9     1     9  0.5  1.5  8.5  9.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
15 #C1FFAD 1 16     1    16  0.5  1.5 15.5 16.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
16 #C4FFB1 1 14     1    14  0.5  1.5 13.5 14.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
17 #E4FFDA 1  2     1     2  0.5  1.5  1.5  2.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
18 #FFFFFF 1 12     1    12  0.5  1.5 11.5 12.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
19 #D6FFC8 1  6     1     6  0.5  1.5  5.5  6.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
20 #9CFF83 1 22     1    22  0.5  1.5 21.5 22.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
21 #DFFFD3 1 11     1    11  0.5  1.5 10.5 11.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
22 #DFFFD3 1  8     1     8  0.5  1.5  7.5  8.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
23 #C7FFB5 1 21     1    21  0.5  1.5 20.5 21.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
24 #CEFFBC 1  7     1     7  0.5  1.5  6.5  7.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
25 #FAFFF8 1  3     1     3  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
26 #A87FFF 1 27     1    27  0.5  1.5 26.5 27.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
27 #FF6140 1 26     1    26  0.5  1.5 25.5 26.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
28 #C7FFB5 2 19     1    46  1.5  2.5 18.5 19.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
29 #E2FFD6 2 20     1    47  1.5  2.5 19.5 20.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
30 #FFFFFF 2  1     1    28  1.5  2.5  0.5  1.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
31 #CEFFBC 2 13     1    40  1.5  2.5 12.5 13.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
32 #DFFFD3 2 10     1    37  1.5  2.5  9.5 10.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
33 #DFFFD3 2 15     1    42  1.5  2.5 14.5 15.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
34 #CBFFB9 2 18     1    45  1.5  2.5 17.5 18.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
35 #CEFFBC 2 17     1    44  1.5  2.5 16.5 17.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
36 #F5FFF0 2  5     1    32  1.5  2.5  4.5  5.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
37 #C4FFB1 2 25     1    52  1.5  2.5 24.5 25.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
38 #E2FFD6 2  4     1    31  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
39 #B4FF9E 2 24     1    51  1.5  2.5 23.5 24.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
40 #DCFFCF 2 23     1    50  1.5  2.5 22.5 23.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
41 #FFFFFF 2  9     1    36  1.5  2.5  8.5  9.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
42 #D3FFC4 2 16     1    43  1.5  2.5 15.5 16.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
43 #E7FFDE 2 14     1    41  1.5  2.5 13.5 14.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
44 #FCFFFB 2  2     1    29  1.5  2.5  1.5  2.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
45 #EFFFE9 2 12     1    39  1.5  2.5 11.5 12.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
46 #EAFFE1 2  6     1    33  1.5  2.5  5.5  6.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
47 #E2FFD6 2 22     1    49  1.5  2.5 21.5 22.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
48 #FAFFF8 2 11     1    38  1.5  2.5 10.5 11.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
49 #F5FFF0 2  8     1    35  1.5  2.5  7.5  8.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
50 #D3FFC4 2 21     1    48  1.5  2.5 20.5 21.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
51 #D9FFCB 2  7     1    34  1.5  2.5  6.5  7.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
52 #EAFFE1 2  3     1    30  1.5  2.5  2.5  3.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
53 #9669FF 2 27     1    54  1.5  2.5 26.5 27.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
54 #FF7F5E 2 26     1    53  1.5  2.5 25.5 26.5     NA  0.1        1    NA    NA     NA
```

When I create my ggplot from this dataframe

```
ggplot(data , aes(x , y , fill = I(fill))) + geom_tile()
```

no legend shows up and no amount of scale_fill_gradient() or scale_color_gradient() helps so far.

exemple that doesn't create a legend:

```
ggplot(gp , aes(x , y , fill = I(fill))) + geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(name='',low = "white",
                      high = "green",
                      na.value = "grey50",
                      guide = "colourbar",
                      aesthetics = "colour")
```

Is there a way of forcing a legend in such a case?

EDIT: Essentially, I want a figure of this type with a legend (at least the green one, but ideally for the three color gradients).

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want the fill colors interpreted literally, so you need `scale_fill_identity`. By default this does not have a legend, so you need to add `guide = 'legend'` to the call:

```r
ggplot(data , aes(x , y , fill = fill)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = 'legend')
```

[image]

You have said that you want a continuous scale, but this is harder, since it is not clear what your continuous scale is supposed to represent, nor what numbers should be on it. To some extent you could back-transform the colors, since I am guessing your initial fills went from pure green to pure white. This means that you can back-transform the colors into a numerical value between 0 and 1:

```r
ggplot(data , aes(x , y , fill = (colSums(col2rgb(fill))-255)/510)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 1), name = NULL,
                      low = 'green', high = 'white')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I see it seems to be pretty tricky. One thing I'd like to add is that, actually, for different values of y, I have different color gradients (green for some, red for others). That's why I had to manipulate the ggplots with layer_data. Hence I cannot easily convert back the colors to a numerical between 0 and 1.

Comment: @larmor so what is it that you want to do? I have added a gradient scale here based on the data you provided, but it is difficult to see what else you expect given the information in your question.

Comment: I added datapoints to the dataset and linked to the kind of figure I have in mind.

Comment: @larmor but what is it that the legend is supposed to represent? What numbers are supposed to be on it? What label? What does it _mean_? A legend represents a mapping of a color to a value, but we only have the color here, and not the value it is supposed to represent.

Comment: in my original dataframe, to each combination of (x,y) corresponds a measurement, a continuous value, that I mapped onto a color gradient. But because values of y = 26 and 27 are peculiar, I want them to have a different color gradient (the 3 color gradients go from white to red, green and blue). So I created three ggplot with geom_tiles (each with a different color gradient), extracted their layer_data() and merged them. Once this was done, I plotted the heatmap but I'm unable to display even a bogus color gradient.

Comment: @larmor so what numbers should appear on the gradient scale?

Comment: The 3 color scales are made so that low (white) is 0 and high (red, blue, green) is 20. I understand that these numbers were lost in the process of taking layer_data().